# pandas str new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I encounter a problem:

```
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame([['ab','b'],['cc','d'],['ab','d']],columns=['id','table'])
```

the df like this:

```
    id table
 0  ab     b
 1  cc     d
 2  ab     d
```

I wanted to get the result:

```
   id table             gram
0  ab     b  select ab from b
1  cc     d  select cc from d
2  ab     d  select ab from d
```

I try to use str method to get the result,but I don't know how to convert StringMethods' object to str. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['gram'] = 'select ' + df.id + ' from ' + df.table
print (df)
   id table              gram
0  ab     b  select ab from b
1  cc     d  select cc from d
2  ab     d  select ab from d
```

Solution with `apply`, but it is very slow:

```
df['gram'] = df.apply(lambda x: "select {} from {}".format(x.id, x.table), axis=1)
```

---

```
import pandas
df=pandas.DataFrame([['ab','b'],['cc','d'],['ab','d']],columns=['id','table'])
#[30000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)


In [34]: %timeit df['gram'] = 'select ' + df.id + ' from ' + df.table
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit df['gram1'] = df.apply(lambda x: "select {} from {}".format(x.id, x.table), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.42 s per loop
```